# How to restrict the '.' or ',' in a string using regex patterns

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie to regex patterns. Need help here...
I have a regex pattern

```
String s = "^[0-9]*([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$";
```

Now the pattern is accepting decimals numbers like `1.2, 1.3, 1.4`,  and also `1,2  3,4   4,5`

The above regex pattern is also accepting single character `,`  or `.` which it should not. How can I change it? :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add what should pass and what shouldn't.

Comment: It should not allow   single character like .   and ,
It should allow  decimal numbers like 1.2   .2   2.  and also  1,2   ,2    2,

Comment: I would suggest using a `NumberFormat` and attempting `parse` in the correct `Locale`.

Comment: OK, you've already said but what about `0`, `1.`, `.2`

Comment: @Toto    It should allow  0,     1.   ,   .2    1,    ,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?![.,]$)(?:\d|\d*[.,]?\d{0,2})$
```

matches:

- `0`
- `1.`
- `.2`
- `1,`
- `,2`

Doesn't match:

- empty
- `.`
- `,`

as requested

Comment: It should not accept single character like   ','  or  '.'     @toto

Comment: @Ramhakrishna: see my edit, I've added a lookahead that makes sure we have not dot or comma alone

Answer (score 1):

Within the group use `{1,2}` as digit repetition to avoid matching `,` or `.` character.

```
^[0-9]*([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Although you can use `\d` for digit group.

```
^\d*([,.]\d{1,2})?$
```

---

**UPDATE :** Use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid single `,` or `.` character match. In addition, this would match digit followed by `,` or `.`.

```
^(?!\D$)\d*([,.]\d{0,2})?$
// or    
^(?![,.]$)\d*([,.]\d{0,2})?$
```

Comment: It is restricting single character ',' or  '.'  but it is also restricting 1,  and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
{0,2}
```

that says: the second group can be EMPTY (because the regex accepts zero to 2 digits). You can change it to

```
{1,2}
```

to indicate: at minimum one digit!

Alternatively/in addition: you could also change the first part `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` - if you want to **enforce** that values need to **start** with a digit! (right now, you would accept input such as ".05" - maybe you want to allow for that, maybe not)